# Python - Range()

Tags: python, range

I'm new to Python, I have tried to create a simple loop in order for me to list users that has userID of value integer. However the userID on the DB seems weird (Users 1-72 are displayed properly, next to 72 is 712 already), so I need to skip those users who does not have any userID 73-711. What exception must be done or do I need to create a simple if else?

```
for iD in range(1, 720):
        loginID = iD
        for users in tls.getUserByID(loginID):
            fname = users.get('firstName')
            lname = users.get('lastName')
            print(loginID, fname +" "+ lname)
```

The error I'm getting is..

```
raise testlinkerrors.TLResponseError(
testlink.testlinkerrors.TLResponseError: NO_USER_BY_ID_LOGIN: (getUserByID) - Cannot Find User with DB ID (73)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre]. We don't care about your background as a programmer - we *do* care about a *clear, specific* question that gives appropriate context for the problem. What is `tls`? What database are you talking about? What does the question actually have to do with `range` - it seems like you are trying to ask how to skip certain numbers? Except - **what is the rule** that actually tells you which numbers to use for the `iD` value? "However the userID on the DB seems weird" **How do you know** about the numbers?

Comment: Did you try *using code to check* what numbers are valid for the `iD`, for example *by reading them from the database*? Did you try *checking the documentation* for `tls`, to see if it provides a more direct way to iterate over the users?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - hello tls.getUserByID is the api call in order for me to display details of the user, pre-requisites requirement in order to display the specific user is to have declare user id which is present in the db. Those user id are just normal integers starting from 1 up to max number of the users present. I have already use the answer from the other comments and it seems it is now working as expected, now I'm finding a way if there are much more faster way to skip the id's that are not present in the db :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this @ckmb

```
     for iD in range(60, 720):
        if iD not in [* range(73, 712)]:
            loginID = iD
            try:
                api_getUser = tls.getUserByID(loginID)
                for user in api_getUser:
                  fname = user.get('firstName')
                  lname = user.get('lastName')
                  print(loginID, fname + " " + lname)
            except testlinkerrors.TLResponseError:
                print(loginID, "not found")
                continue
```

Comment: -hi! i tried it and it skips 73-711 :) however I have another server on the loop which has normal list of users like there are some valeus in 73 and so on. Maybe I'll just find a way to this. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You will get exception when call `tls.getUserByID(loginID)` if no user with DB ID, so you need to handle the exception `testlinkerrors.TLResponseError` by `try/except` statement.

```py
from testlink.testlinkerrors import TLResponseError

for iD in range(1, 720):
    loginID = iD
    try:
        users = tls.getUserByID(loginID)
    except TLResponseError:
        print(loginID, "not found !")
        continue
    for user in users:
        fname = user.get('firstName')
        lname = user.get('lastName')
        print(loginID, fname +" "+ lname)
```

Comment: should we define first testlinkerrors as I received NameError: name 'testlinkerrors' is not defined

Comment: it seems there were no module available. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Testlink_Users_IDLoop.py", line 4, in <module>
    import testlinkerrors
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testlinkerrors`

Comment: It is something like you call `tls.getUserByID` which should be defined before you call it, so import `TLResponseError` required before you call it, or `from testlink.testlinkerrors import TLResponseError` if you use `TestLink-API-Python-client`, update as above.

Comment: it seems it is working fine right now, but are there any ways on how to quickly jump over the next present userID? 73-711 is a long wait that increase runtime. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: I know nothing about this `testlink`, so not sure how to get all existing IDs before you call `tls.getUserByID`.

Comment: I mean, are there any ways skipping 73-711 more faster?

Comment: IMO, the answer is No. Time spent on when `tls.getUserByID` called, not on the loop 73 ~ 711 which may spend time much less than 1ms.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the failures with a simple try/except block.

```py
for iD in range(1, 720):
        loginID = iD
        try:
            for users in tls.getUserByID(loginID):
                fname = users.get('firstName')
                lname = users.get('lastName')
                print(loginID, fname +" "+ lname)
        except testlinkerrors.TLResponseError:
            print("Skipping iD")
            continue
```

Comment: Catching *all* exceptions with a blanket `except` clause like that is a bad idea that hides actual bugs.

Comment: it seems OP is not interested in catching any bugs. He wants to send requests against an incomplete table. A blank except is explicit in that the goal is not to catch bugs.

Comment: @user2357112 hi - so what's the best way in order to continue the loop even though 73-711 is not present in the DB?

Comment: I think they suggest being explicit in which error you are skipping. See updated code

Comment: Error Occured: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Testlink_Users_IDLoop.py", line 42, in <module>
    serverList()
  File "Testlink_Users_IDLoop.py", line 38, in serverList
    except testlinkerrors.TLResponseError:
NameError: name 'testlinkerrors' is not defined

Comment: you may have to import testlinkerrors - or just catch all exceptions and ignore the dogmatism preached above. As you get more confident with python and understand what exceptions are you can improve your code. (unless you are trying to create reusable code, in which case be aware that there is a reason why catching all exceptions is said to be a bad idea - it can indeed hide bugs)

Comment: @dangom - thanks I have imported testlinkerrors module

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple function that takes an iterable and a range of numbers to skip and returns a generator.

```
def skip(iter, start, end):
    return (i for i in iter if not (i <= end and i >= start))
```

And now:

```
list(skip(range(1, 720), 73, 711))
```

Yields:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 
 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 
 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 
 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 712, 713, 
 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719]
>>>
```

Comment: let me try this, btw just to give you some info, this is only one instance for my testlink, I assume there are also other db that has weird ID values.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the answer of @Jason Yang - and it seems this is what I'm expecting to have, however I believe skipping 73-711 will increase runtime, are there any ways on how to automatically skip them? Like if these int are not present in the range, then skip

```
for iD in range(60, 720):
        loginID = iD
        try:
            api_getUser = tls.getUserByID(loginID)
        except testlinkerrors.TLResponseError:
            print (loginID, "not found")
            continue
        for user in api_getUser:
            fname = user.get('firstName')
            lname = user.get('lastName')
            print(loginID, fname + " " + lname)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of way to get some subset of some range of number

If you know the boundaries you can use [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain(range(10),range(100,110),range(210,222)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221]
>>>
```

for your example is `itertools.chain(range(73),range(712,720))`, that way you don't waste time with something you alredy know is not going to work.

You can use filtering like in Chris answer

You can use try-except and just processing the successful ones

You can combine the two above by remembering the problematic ones, saving it somewhere, and use that to filter. For the saving part, if we want to remember after closing the program, we can use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module to save it into a file

Like for example

```
from testlink.testlinkerrors import TLResponseError
import json

ignore_file = "ignore_id.json" 
#to_ignore = set()

def fun(users, to_ignore=()):
    to_ignore = set(to_ignore)
    for iD in users:
        loginID = iD
        if iD in to_ignore:
            print(loginID, "ignored !")
            continue 
        try:
            users = tls.getUserByID(loginID)
        except TLResponseError:
            print(loginID, "not found !")
            to_ignore.add(iD)
            continue
        for user in users:
            fname = user.get('firstName')
            lname = user.get('lastName')
            print(loginID, fname +" "+ lname)
    return to_ignore


def load_json(file_name):
    try:
        with open(file_name) as file: 
            return json.load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return []

def save_json(file_name,data):
    with open(file_name,"w") as file:
        json.dump(data,file)




to_ignore = fun(range(1,720), load_json(ignore_file))
save_json(ignore_file,list(to_ignore))
```

EDIT:

You can also generalize the function to take the user and the list to ignore and whatever else it might need, and it can return the set of problematic user it found along the way and do something appropriate with that info.

Now with the function now generalize like that, you can do different types of call such as

```
fun(range(1,720))
fun(itertools.chain(range(73),range(712,720))
fun(range(1,113)) #for the other database
etc...
```

Comment: thanks for this detailed answer, this really help :). Now I'm looking for a way, since I have a lot of db which other userID on that particular db is not the same as I'm using right now for test. My full script loops in every db, one has nice set of user id that does not have any skipped values(example. 1-112 users) (the one I'm using right now is having 1-72 then next is 712 and so on). So I think, I cannot hardcode in ignore_id.json

Comment: @ckmb you can always generalize the function, you can make it so it take the list of user, the one to ignore from that list (if any), and whatever else it need to work and return the set of problematic user it found, and save that in a different file for each DB you're working with

Comment: or as other mention, try to find a way to ask the database directly for the valid user instead of blindly trying if that one works or not

Comment: okay, thank you for your suggestions! This is a big help for me :)